# Pandas Group Columns into Level

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have a dataframe of the form:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['2012', 'A', 1], ['2012', 'B', 2], ['2011', 'A', 3], 
                       ['2011', 'B', 2]],
                      columns=['branch_year', 'branch_name', 'employee_id'])

  branch_year branch_name  employee_id
0        2012           A            1
1        2012           B            2
2        2011           A            3
3        2011           B            2
```

How can I combine columns `branch_year` and `branch_name` so that they have a parent column `branch` -- and ideally renaming them to get rid of `branch_` prefix.

```
       branch      branch  employee_id
         year        name
0        2012           A            1
1        2012           B            2
2        2011           A            3
3        2011           B            2
```

The end goal is to create a list of dictionaries of the form:

```
[
    {
      "employeed_id": 1,
      "branch": {
                  "name": "A",
                  "year": "2012"
      }
    },
    {...}
]
```

Comment: Something like: `df.columns.names= MultiIndex.from_tuples(original.split('_') for original in df.columns.names)`...but that's probably not quite right for a bunch of reasons.

Comment: Correction: you don't need the `.names` bit on `columns`, and you need to pass the sequence as list.  Also, although it doesn't quite do what you want, have you tried `to_json(orient='records')`?  Perhaps you could create an issue (or pull request) for producing json with nested dicts for `MultiIndex`ed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a function to each row and turn the result into a list:

```
def to_nested_dict(row):
    return {'employee_id': row.employee_id,
            'branch': {'year': row.branch_year, 'name': row.branch_name}}

list(df.apply(to_nested_dict, axis=1))
```

This preserves the original order of the rows:

```
[{'branch': {'name': 'A', 'year': '2012'}, 'employee_id': 1},
 {'branch': {'name': 'B', 'year': '2012'}, 'employee_id': 2},
 {'branch': {'name': 'A', 'year': '2011'}, 'employee_id': 3},
 {'branch': {'name': 'B', 'year': '2011'}, 'employee_id': 2}]
```

Programmatic approach nested on column names that have underscores:

```
def to_nested_dict(row):
    res = {}
    for col in row.index:
        outer_key, inner_key = col.split('_')
        outer = res.setdefault(outer_key, {})
        outer[inner_key] = row[col]
    return res

list(df.apply(to_nested_dict, axis=1))
```

Result:

```
[{'branch': {'name': 'A', 'year': '2012'}, 'employee': {'id': 1}},
 {'branch': {'name': 'B', 'year': '2012'}, 'employee': {'id': 2}},
 {'branch': {'name': 'A', 'year': '2011'}, 'employee': {'id': 3}},
 {'branch': {'name': 'B', 'year': '2011'}, 'employee': {'id': 2}}]
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to do it programmatically whereby you nest on column names that have underscores? E.g. `{'branch': {'name': 'A', 'year': '2012'}, 'employee': {'id': 1}}`

Comment: Added a version that does it.

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty, but it gets what you want using [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
lst = []
for k,g in pd.groupby(df, by=['branch_name','branch_year']):
    d = {'employee_id': int(g['employee_id']), 'branch': {'name': k[0], 'year': k[1]}}
    lst.append(d)

lst
[{'branch': {'name': 'A', 'year': '2011'}, 'employee_id': 3},
 {'branch': {'name': 'A', 'year': '2012'}, 'employee_id': 1},
 {'branch': {'name': 'B', 'year': '2011'}, 'employee_id': 2},
 {'branch': {'name': 'B', 'year': '2012'}, 'employee_id': 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempts as a programmatic way (assuming you can split by "_"):

```
hierarchy = [original.split('_') for original in df.columns]

def to_nested_dict(row):
    d = defaultdict(dict)
    for keys, field in zip(hierarchy, row.index):
        val = getattr(row, field)
        if len(keys) == 1:
            d[keys[0]] = val
        elif len(a) == 2:
            d[keys[0]][keys[1]] = val
    return d


list(df.apply(to_nested_dict, axis=1))
```